# Javafx: GridPane: Prevent column to grow width when text is too long

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, gridpanel

I have some legacy code to fix and I'm struggling on the following:

I have 2 nested gridpanes. Inside the inner grid, text has to be added.

The column widths of both inner and outer grids are calculated relative to the screen size using following function:

```
private GridPane createGridPane( int []colsPercent, int []rowsPercent ) {
    GridPane gridPane = new GridPane()
    // setup columns
    ColumnConstraints []colConst = new ColumnConstraints[colsPercent.length];
    for( int i = 0 ; i < colsPercent.length ; i++ ) {
        colConst[i] = new ColumnConstraints();
        colConst[i].setPercentWidth(colsPercent[i]);
        colConst[i].setFillWidth(true);
    }
    gridPane.getColumnConstraints().addAll(colConst);
    // setup rows
    RowConstraints []rowConst = new RowConstraints[rowsPercent.length];
    for( int i = 0 ; i < rowsPercent.length ; i++ ) {
        rowConst[i] = new RowConstraints();
        rowConst[i].setPercentHeight(rowsPercent[i]);
        rowConst[i].setFillHeight(true);
    }
    gridPane.getRowConstraints().addAll(rowConst);
    return gridPane;
}
```

The grids and their contents are added by following code:

```
   gridPane = createGridPane(colConstFeedbackScreenPercent,
                rowConstFeedbackScreenPercent);
        gridPane.setGridLinesVisible(true);
        GridPane.setHgrow(gridPane, Priority.NEVER);
        GridPane innerGridPane = createGridPane(colConstFeedbackInnerPercent,
                rowConstFeedbackInnerPercent);
        GridPane.setHgrow(innerGridPane, Priority.NEVER);
        innerGridPane.setGridLinesVisible(true);

        gridPane.add(innerGridPane, 1, 1);
```

If I add text to the inner gridPane, like so:

```
VBox vBox = new VBox();

            vBox.setSpacing(25);
            {
                Text text = new Text(IRAPfx.getData().getOptionString("Localised text 6"));
                text.setFont(Font.font("Arial",FontPosture.ITALIC,FONT_SIZE_INSTRUCTIONS));

                text.setFill(Color.WHITE);

                GridPane.setHgrow(text, Priority.NEVER);
                vBox.getChildren().add(text);
            }

            ...

            GridPane.setHgrow(vBox, Priority.NEVER);
            innerGridPane.add(vBox, 1, 1 + resultsCell );
```

The inner grid, and together with this inner grid the outer grid, will grow when the text string is too large to fit in its cell, resulting in the whole grid (inner and outer) being "stretched" to fit this long contents, and running over the right edge of the screen.

What I would like to archieve is that the long string runs over the outer grid, or even out of the screen if it is really long, but not stretching the whole grid.

As you can see in the code, I tried setting Hgrow to NEVER to no avail. Any suggestions how to fix it (I can't find examples or tips on the www..) would be very welcome.

Thanks in advance,
Joris

Answer (score 2):

I found a partial solution to it:

You can clip or wrap the text to the available width of the cell by using 'label' in stead of 'text'. See below:

For wrapping:

```
           {
                Label label = new Label(IRAPfx.getData().getOptionString("Localised text 6"));
                label.setFont(Font.font("Arial",FontPosture.ITALIC,FONT_SIZE_INSTRUCTIONS));
                label.setWrapText(true);
                label.setTextFill(Color.WHITE);
                vBox.getChildren().add(label);
            }
```

For clipping:

```
           {
                Label label = new Label(IRAPfx.getData().getOptionString("Localised text 6"));
                label.setFont(Font.font("Arial",FontPosture.ITALIC,FONT
                label.setTextOverrun(OverrunStyle.CLIP);
                label.setTextFill(Color.WHITE);
                vBox.getChildren().add(label);
            }
```

This more or less solves my problem, however I still did not manage to let the text run over into the next columns (the ones to the right of the cell where the text/label is put).

Any help on that still welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the setWrappingWidth method on Text object, you can define a predefined with of this way, 200 in this case:

```
text.setWrappingWidth(200);
```

Comment: Thanks Rene, I have tried that method before, and it works. It however does not take into account the different screen widths available. I found a fix myself by using 'label' in stead of 'text'. I will post the solution below

Answer (score 0):

It isn't really clear to me why you have the Text elements inside a VBox before putting them into the GridPane.  But you can do something like this:

```
    vbox.maxWidthProperty().bind(innerGridPane.widthProperty().multiply(innerGridPane.getColumnConstraints().get(1).percentWidthProperty());
    text.wrappingWidthProperty().bind(vbox.maxWidthProperty());
```

Unfortunately, you can't just get a GridPane column and get it's width property to bind it, so you have to recalculate it using the ColumnConstraints properties.

Any case where you need to have items dynamically change behaviours base on window sizes and so on, you'll need to bind the relevant properties together.